# Need help in correcting Typescript Model for a JSON File

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a TS model like below:

```
class Model {
   name: string;
   b: string;
   c: string;
   d: string;
   series: string []
}
```

Now I have a file which is compliant with this TS definition as shown below in flat structure:

```
{
  "MYUSERDATA": [
    {
      "name": "Dumb",
      "b": "B",
      "c": "C",
      "d": "D",
      "series": ["A"]
    },

    {
      "name": "DUMB1",
      "b": "BB",
      "c": "CC",
      "d": "DD",
      "series": ["B"]
    },

    {
      "name": "A",
      "b": "BBB",
      "c": "CCC",
      "d": "DDD",
      "series": ["C"]
    },

    {
      "name": "B",
      "b": "BBBB",
      "c": "CCCC",
      "d": "DDDD",
      "series": []
    }, {
      "name": "C",
      "b": "BBBBB",
      "c": "CCCCC",
      "d": "DDDDD",
      "series": []
    }
  ]

}
```

I want to map some thing like this : If any of the object has series.length>0 , then each key inside the series should be looked upon inside JSON (by name Primary key) and if it finds, then that key should be replace by that entire object. Problem is, what is the best way to handle such case in Typescript and if we mapped, then wont it change the Model definition because series is string array and we will be mapping each key inside this array to object (by looking up inside JSON file)?
Also I am writing my parsing logic as below:

```
const data: Model[] = JSON.parse('JSON File path').MYUSERDATA;
data.forEach((model: Model) => {
 model.series.map((item)=>(fileteredObj))
 // where fileteredObj is the one which came by look up , based on "name" primary key
 
 }
```

SO very first object with name="dumb" will be as follow post mapping:

```
{
      "name": "Dumb",
      "b": "B",
      "c": "C",
      "d": "D",
      "series": [{
       "name": "A",
        "b": "BBB",
        "c": "CCC",
        "d": "DDD",
        "series": [{
          "name": "C",
          "b": "BBBBB",
          "c": "CCCCC",
          "d": "DDDDD",
          "series": []
        }]
      }]
    }
```

```
 public filer(models: Model[],model: Model){
  const newArray=  model.series.map((item)=>{
      const fileredValue: Model=this.filterValue(models,"name",item);
      fileredValue.depth= model.depth+ "." + item;
      if(fileredValue.series.length>0){
       this.filer(models,fileredValue);
      }
      return { item: fileredValue }; // Line A
    })
    return newArray;
  }
  
 public filterValue(obj: any, key: string, value: string): any {
    return obj.find(function (v: any) { return v[key] === value });
 }
```

Comment: it changes the type to `series: (string|Model)[]`

Comment: Thanks Thomas , Also I am writing my parsing and merging logic as above , do you think it is best way of doing things in TS or any other optimization can be done ?

Comment: Is the order in `MYUSERDATA` relevant? Or could you guarantee that `{ "name": "A" }` will always be in the list before any `{ "series": ["A"] }`? In that case you could return the full structure right out if `JSON.parse()`

Comment: MYUSERDATA , I just took as delimiter , so that I can get all objects of Model in an array. and there is no order , they can come in any order and it can be recursrive also i.e in more depth level. Example : when I say series["A"] , then A itself can have series members and so on. So after merge or map series will have many objects and not all necessarily will be on same level. Also series length need not to be one only. It can be like this also series["A","B"] , in that case it should pull both objects (if at all in JSON file there are objects with "name" attribute as A and B)

Comment: I have edited example, just to clarify more ,So series["A"] points to object with name "A" but "A" itself points to name "C" . Hence object with name ="Dumb" will eventually have a series with A and C but in nested fashion which shows that Dumb has child A and A has child C and it should be possible because we defined series of type Model [] also. So I mainly want to maintain one pointer for each object inside this JSON file which gives me depth of children . Like for very first object , it will be Dumb.A.C

Comment: Sample post merge for object name="dumb", I pasted in post for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Typescript Types

I am assuming that you might have multiple different models, so we'll create a generic type  and then apply it to `Model`.

We want to map from a given model `M` to its nested version.  That means all of the properties except for `series` stay the same.  We replace the original property `series`, which was `string[]`, with an array of other deeply nested models.

```
type NestedSeries<M> = Omit<M, 'series'> & {
    series: NestedSeries<M>[];
}
```

For your specific model, you would set the generic `M` to `Model`.

```
type Res = NestedSeries<Model>
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/PmLz4w)

Note: There are (much more complicated) ways to do this based on the string literal values. But the data that you get from `JSON.parse` will not have string literal values to begin with, so that doesn't help.

#### Implementation

You've also asked for the code to do the conversion.  I [wrote a class](https://codesandbox.io/s/nesting-flat-model-data-e4v2b?file=/src/ModelFormatter.ts) to do this and [tested it](https://codesandbox.io/s/nesting-flat-model-data-e4v2b?file=/src/ModelFormatter.test.ts) with your data.  There's a lot of comments in the code so I won't write much here, but basically If we look up the series' from the top down then we can ensure that we include everything without encountering any loops.

```
/**
 * class converts an array of models into a nested hierarchy
 */
export class ModelFormatter<M extends Nestable> {
  /**
   * The raw data that was passed to the constructor
   * A flat array with no nesting
   */
  private data: M[];

  /**
   * Parse each series into a complete tree
   */
  public readonly tree: NestedSeries<M>[] = [];

  constructor(data: M[]) {
    this.data = data;
    const names = this.data.map((model) => model.name);
    // find the top-level models to start with
    const topLevel = names.filter(this.isTopLevel);
    // apply nesting from the top level down
    this.tree = topLevel.map(this.findNestedModel);
  }

  /**
   * Create helper methods to be used in the constructor.
   * Need to define these as arrow functions in order to have proper
   * `this` context when using as callbacks for map/filter.
   */

  /**
   * A model is at the top level if its name does not appear in the
   * series array of any other model.
   */
  private isTopLevel = (name: string): boolean => {
    return this.data.every((model) => !model.series.includes(name));
  };

  /**
   * Lookup the non-nested model by name.
   * Assume that all models should exist and throw an error if not found.
   */
  private findModel = (name: string): M => {
    const model = this.data.find((model) => model.name === name);
    if (!model) {
      throw new Error("no model with name " + name);
    }
    return model;
  };

  /**
   * Retrieve a model and also fill in its children recursively
   */
  private findNestedModel = (name: string): NestedSeries<M> => {
    const model = this.findModel(name);
    return {
      ...model,
      series: model.series.map((n) => this.findNestedModel(n))
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: THanks Linda  . Thats sound good.  But how we will merge the objects , I mean it can be done in linear fashion only right i.e one by one ? And after merging , I also dont want to delete merged object from JSON file. For example: Object with name="Dumb1" has series["B"] but  post merging , I don't want to remove object name="B" and it will remain as it is in JSON file. I am worried because for merging (i.e replace series elements by actual objects) has to be in linear fashion and look up for series elements also has to be in linear fashion using find() etc. method.

Comment: For example: I have updated the code in above post, like how I am using. (See the filer method) .I am bit confused at Line A , how to return mapped object ?  Also I have taken one pointer depth , which I am able to get and it shows at which nested level we reached.

Comment: I didn’t realize you needed the implementation as well as the types.  I can look at this again tomorrow but I think it’s simpler than than you are making it.

Comment: ok sure Linda . I thought that I will transform series of keys as series of pointers and this pointer will help in searching .

Comment: THanks Linda , your answer seems great . The only thing , I think I need to tweak in this logic is that , during merging I dont want to remove actual objects. Post merging every object should be self contained ( so counts of top level objects inside original array should match count of top level objects post merging)

Comment: Just changing single line in constructor did the job  this.tree = names.map(this.findNestedModel);  (i.e I did not map topLevel , rather I mapped all names) and it worked . Thanks a lot Linda !